# How can I resize an iframe element to change with the screen size?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an `iframe` element (specifically, a business intelligence dashboard) that needs to be embedded into a website. There is an "HTML editor" on the website's "back end" (i.e., a portion within the website that is designated for page admins).

Copying and pasting the `iframe` code and subsequently adjusting the height and width to properly fit the screen worked fine- but if I open the window on another screen, the `iframe` dimensions don't adjust for the different screen size.

Unfortunately, I don't think I have access to any CSS files in the company website (i.e., I don't think I have the ability to upload a CSS file), so I'm not too sure what I can do with most suggestions on SO. Does anyone know how I can set the `iframe` dimensions to be dynamic?

Web development isn't my speciality, so if I could provide better information, feel free to ask in the comments section.

**Edited to add:**
Following the first two responses, I inserted the HTML line

```
<iframe style="width:100%; height:500px;overflow:auto;">
```

and the iframe definitely changed sizes- but unfortunately, the grey space behind it (is that padding?) began appearing in different sizes, depending on the computer screen size. I've taken the following picture, with the red arrows pointing to grey space I'd like filled with the iframe and the blue arrows pointing to the iframe itself:

[image]

Here is the new code in the HTML editor, but with the link changed (to keep it anonymous):

```
<center>
    <div>
        <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 710px; overflow: auto;" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=abc123..." frameborder="0" width="320" height="240">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</center>
```

For what it's worth, I've tried to delete the `width="320" height="240"` snippet at the end of the `<iframe>` tag, but as I click "update" in the HTML editor, the snippet reappears.

Answer (score 5):

Even though you don't have direct access to the CSS, you can still change css by using inline styles.

The way you do that is by using the `style=""` inside the tag you want to change the CSS styles.

The way you make the width dynamic is by using the size as percentage instead of pixels.

---

For example:

```
<iframe style="border: 0; width:100%; height: 500px; overflow: auto;" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

Notice the `width:100%;`, this will cause the iframe to always be 100% of the screen size. The height will always be 500px, but you can change it to whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks. The advice worked, but I'm wondering how I can dynamically change the iframe element to fill in the  grey padding behind it; I've updated my question above to explain better.

Comment: @daOnlyBG Is that gray space inside the iframe?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: @daOnlyBG put a border around the iframe `border:3px solid #000;` just so you can see the outline of the iframe. If the gray space is inside the border than it is part of the iframe window.

Answer (score 4):

You can use inline styling in the `iframe` element. Have a look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nLaL5b61/).

I set width to 100%, which means it will resize to whatever the size of the container. The height is fixed, but if it can't fit inside the container the `overflow: auto;` will make the scrolls show up.

```
<div>
  <iframe style="width:100%; height:500px;overflow:auto;">

  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Following your advice, I did get the element to resize. However, I noticed that as the element changes size, a grey background around it appears in different thicknesses depending on the screen size. Please see my edit in the OP- thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code what you are writing to embed the `iframe`?

Comment: Sure- please see my OP.

Comment: Try removing the `width` and `height` from the `iframe` element, just leave the `width` and `height` inside the `style`. And remove the `<center></center>`, see which part of the container it fills. If you have other `div`s try changing their color to see what is occupying that grey area.

Comment: Sadly, removing both didn't work- the problem persists. In fact, each time I click the "update HTML" option, the `width="320" height="240"` snippet returns.

Comment: It seems like it is being overwritten by some other css that you have no control over. Did you try playing with borders and background colors, to see which components are occupying that grey area?